# Swift - How to overload += for Int to pass the operator as a parameter in a function call like nextPage(page: pageIndex += 1)?

Tags: ios, swift, math, operator-overloading, inout

I would like to know how I can do the following please:-

```
    // This is not correct
    func += (inout lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int {
        return lhs + rhs
    }


Objective Usage:- scrollTo(pageIndex: pageIndex += 1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is close, but it needs to do two things:

1. Add the right hand side to the left hand side
2. Return the new value.

Your code only returns the new value, it does not update the left hand side value.  In theory, you could use this:

```swift
func += (lhs: inout Int, rhs: Int) -> Int {
    lhs = lhs + rhs
    return lhs
}
```

But there is another problem; The standard += operator has a `void` return type and you have defined a new operator with an `Int` return type.

If you try and use the `+=` operator in a context where a void return type is acceptable (which is the normal use of this operator) the compiler will give an ambiguity error, since it can't determine which function it should use:

```
someIndex += 1   // This will give an ambiguity compile time error
```

You can address this by defining the operator using generics, where the arguments conform to `AdditiveArithmetic` (Thanks to @NewDev for this tip)
:

```swift
func +=<T: AdditiveArithmetic> (lhs: inout T, rhs: T) -> T {
    lhs = lhs + rhs
    return lhs
}
```

I must say, however, that this does seem like quite a lot of complexity to add, when you could simply have two lines of code; one to increment the `pageIndex` and then a call to the function.

Comment: Thank you for the response it is pretty much what I am after, I was really hoping I could use the += but yes I understand it causes the ambiguity error but I am just wondering is there a way to still override the existing behaviour so that it behaves the way it should but also in addition to this I can pass it as an argument using += instead of &= ? sorry if its a dumb question but have to ask :]

Comment: No, because you aren't overriding the original operator.  The original operator is `func +=(Int,Int)->Void` and the new operator is `func +=(Int,Int)->Int` - There is no way to tell the compiler which one you mean in a non-assignment context.

Comment: You can also address it by making this overload use a generic, so it's a lower priority relative to the normal `+=`: `func +=<T: AdditiveArithmetic>(lhs: inout T, rhs: T) -> T {...}`

Comment: You could resolve the ambiguity in a non-assignment case like this `(i += 20) as Void` but that is really lousy as you can see.

Comment: @vacawama Yes you can also use `let _:Int = i += 1` which is even lousier :). The generic solution is nice.

Comment: I wouldn't want to have to code review code that was using this.

Comment: You guys are geniuses I knew there is a genius out there that will get this to work. Thank you all @Paulw11 and NewDev :]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood you but, if I did i would be something like this

func nextPage(n1: Int) -> Int {

var number = n1 + 1
return number
}